# How do you determine if a QVariant representing a QObject* is null

Tags: c++, qt

I'm using `QMetaObject` to get properties from my object, some of these properties are pointers to classes that inherit from QObject, when using `QMetaProperty::read` I get back a `QVariant` containing the pointer to the value of that property.

Given that `QVariant` I'm unable to determine if the underlying value is null or not.

I've written a unit test to show the issue assuming you already have the `QVariant`

```
TEST(utilsTests, isNull)
{
    QObject* object1 = new QObject();
    QObject* object2 = nullptr;
    EXPECT_NE(nullptr, object1);
    EXPECT_TRUE(object2 == nullptr);
    QVariant variant1 = QVariant::fromValue(object1);
    QVariant variant2 = QVariant::fromValue(object2);
    EXPECT_FALSE(Utils::isNull(variant1));//test passes
    EXPECT_TRUE(Utils::isNull(variant2));//test fails
}
```

And here's what I've tried for the implementation of `Utils::isNull`

```
bool Utils::isNull(QVariant value)
{
    return value.isNull() ||
            value.data() == nullptr ||
            value.data() == NULL ||
            value.data_ptr().is_null == 1 ||
            value == QVariant() ||
            value == NULL;
}
```

Some other things I've tried include:

1. `value.canConvert<QObject*>()` however this throws a segfault
2. `value.value<QObject*>() == nullptr` this a also throws a segfault
3. `value.value<void*>() == nullptr` this always returns true

The reason I'm trying to do this is to convert arbitrary QObjects to json, but that's not important in this scope.

Comment: What is the metatype type for the qvariant causing you the headache?

Comment: the meta type is QObject*

Comment: Can you give me the line of code you used to determine that?

Comment: calling `variant1.typeName()` returns the metatype as a string, you could also call `.type()` to get the enum.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

After some more experimentation I discovered that you can just compare 2 QVariants, if they are both representing a null pointer it will return true, otherwise it will return false. My final implementation of isNull looks like this:

```
bool Utils::isNull(QVariant value)
{
    //declaring a static variable here, it only get's initlized the first time
    static QVariant nullVariant = QVariant::fromValue((QObject * const)nullptr);
    return value == nullVariant;
}
```

you might want to call `value.isNull()` as well so you don't get any false positives.